# Mi server no tiene URLs temporales

Tags: url, cpanel

Tengo un plan del tipo Reseller y antes podía acceder mediante URLs temporales del tipo  `ip/~myweb`, pero ahora han desactivado esta opción y ya no se puede acceder así.

Me han dicho que edite el archivo hosts de Windows como:

```
123.45.67.89 www.example.com
```

pero esto no es una buena solución para mí.

¿Se podrá hacer algo vía cpanel o php para apuntar enlaces a estas web?

Esto es debido a que tengo webs que no utilizan un nombre de dominio, por lo tanto debo generar estos enlaces directos como lo hacía con las url temporales.

Comment: I think you are on the wrong SO, this is in spanish, go to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @maudichili viendo que ya publicaste respuestas en español, ¿podrías traducir está pregunta? Encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.